# PHP - Divide et Impera to avoid Fatal Error: Maxim execution time exceeded

Tags: php, time, resources, max

everyone!

I am building an 'Seeker' to get some prices from 7 websites. I am using cUrl to get this prices and I am dealing with this problem: Fatal Error: Maximum execution exceeded. I have read about this and saw some solutions, but I want to know if I can divide the process more than it is. So here is my app:

The customer enters on my website, search for some codes of items (the *worst* case is the one of 5 different codes once) and send a request for price. So I am posting an array of maximum 5 codes to my MainController that distributes the array on every single controller, like this:

```
$codesArray -> MainController -> foreach(ControllersList as Controller){Controller->getPrices($codesArray)}
```

I assume that the time execution is distributed wrong, or not as I want, because I have tested it with 3 codes and the *"Fatal Error: maximum execution time: **30 seconds**"* comes at 33 seconds from the begining, on the fifth controller. I think is impossible to search for 3 items 4 times in 3 seconds and exceed on the fifth, so it means the server is counting the MainController process, not every process itself. My question is how can I divide properly the process to obtain the distribution of time per controller?

I hope I made myself understood, sorry for bad english and also bad explanation.

**NOTE:** I tested each controller with an array of 7 codes and I have never get this Fatal Error, that is why I want to divide the process, but I am not sure how..

**NOTE II:** Send one code once will result in n*7 more curl executions because with the array the process repeats just the search functions, not the whole connect to website-> check login -> login* -> search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer is related to the request as a whole, is not split on the different controller calls. The whole execution time can't exceed 30 seconds (you can increase the time limit in `php.ini`.
And also, they are not multiple processes: PHP is single-threaded, so you cant spawn another thread and run it. You can try making the calls in parallel using [`curl_multi_init()`](http://php.net/curl_multi_init) and then doing the processing (I'm assuming the calls take more time than the actual processing).

Comment: Yes, the error is on the curl_exec($ch); line. I will try this, thank's for the explanation!  I will try it and see the results. Another question, if I will split the controllers by the execution time, like this 3 on MoreTimeExecution and 4 LessTImeExecution and call each with ajax will result in 30 seconds for each category because ajax is making 2 requests ?